# input type="datetime-local" valueAsDate return null

Tags: javascript, html

`<input name="datetime" type="datetime-local" />`

The above input only works with `valueAsNumber`, when I switch to `valueAsDate` it returns null.

I guess it's because failed to convert into `Date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is not a date, it is a date*time*

You are correct, it failed to convert into Date.

You could do this instead:

```
var datevalue = new Date(myinput.value);
```